# Excel VBA insert date where cell blank

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in a spread sheet that is populated with date information, as it stands it is given to me as just a year. In order for it to be read properly I need to reformat the information into a proper date format and so I have attempted to do the following:

```
With ActiveSheet
    RowCount = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A5", Range("A5").End(xlDown)))
End With

  For k = 1 To RowCount

      If ActiveCell.Range(15, k + 1).Value = "" Then
            ActiveCell.Range(15, k + 1).Value = "01/01/9999"
        Else
            ActiveSheet.Range(15, k + 1).Value = "01/01/" & ActiveSheet.Range(15, k + 1).Value
        End If

Next k
```

However none of my cells are populating, any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked the value of RowCount?

Comment: Yes, in this example my RowCount variable is set to 91

Comment: Only just noticed your sytax is off, it should be `Cells(15,k+1)`.

Comment: Another syntax error `ActiveCell.Range` should be `Activesheet.Cells`

Comment: `ActiveCell.Cells(15, k+1)` probably isn't returning the cell you're expecting.  If the `ActiveCell` is `A1` then `ActiveCell.Cells(2,1)` will return `A2` - row 2 using the `ActiveCell` as the starting point, so `ActiveCell.Cells(15,k+1)` will return a cell address 15 rows below the ActiveCell and k+1 columns across.

Comment: Thanks for the update, correct changing this to Cells(15,K+1) does put it 15 rows down not 15 columns across as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RowCount` could be returning an incorrect count.

A date is stored in the cell as a number - just adding `01/01/` to it does work, but is open to so many possible errors.  If, for example, a cell contained *SO* it will happily turn it to *01/01/SO*.

Your first run could return correct values such as `01/01/2018` and incorrect values such as `01/01/SO`.  Run it again and the code will happily give you `01/01/01/01/2018` and `01/01/01/01/SO` as it's just adding `01/01/` onto the front each time.

I'd suggest rather than just adding `01/01/` to the value pass the year into `DateSerial` which will convert it to a real date if it can.

```
Sub TurnToDate()

    Dim wrkSht As Worksheet
    Dim lLastRow As Long
    Dim k As Long

    On Error GoTo Err_Handle

    Set wrkSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lLastRow = wrkSht.Cells(wrkSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    With wrkSht
        For k = 1 To lLastRow
            If .Cells(k, 1) = "" Then
                .Cells(k, 1) = DateSerial(9999, 1, 1)
            Else
                'Overflow or type mismatch errors may occur here.
               .Cells(k, 1) = DateSerial(.Cells(k, 1), 1, 1)
            End If
        Next k
    End With

Exit Sub

Err_Handle:

    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 13, 6 '13 = Type Mismatch, 6 = Overflow
            'Occurs if text or date already exists in cell.
            'Clears the error and resumes execution on line following error.
            Resume Next
        Case Else
            MsgBox Err.Description, vbOKOnly, Err.Number
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, adding the DateSerial was a winner!